# Is it possible to remove the “standard” post format?

Tags: wordpress

I want to remove default post format from backhanded and fronted using fronted submission but its not working. i did you `remove_theme_support` but it removes all post format. my code is :

first i removed all post format and then use add new but it's again add default "standard" format

```
function remove_post_formats() {
remove_theme_support('post-formats');
add_theme_support('post-formats',array('chat','audio'));
}
add_action ('after_setup_theme', 'remove_post_formats', 11);
```

Comment: i don't think you can and even if you wanted to know you will have to dig deep into the core as it is a WP core default and it is not added into the functions.php file by add_theme_support()

Comment: ohk let me check sir

Comment: Duplicate: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41940/is-it-possible-to-remove-the-standard-post-format